# Json data validation for with quotes and without quotes for number data type

Tags: java, json, streaming, sqoop

Data extracted from Oracle DB using a different method ( Sqoop/ real-time streaming) and extracted data stored in JSON format.

JSON Data validation in Java: Sometimes number data type data from Oracle converted as `column_id: "100"` and sometimes `100` in with out quotes. 
How to difference data with quotes and without quotes using Java.

Sample JSON with quotes:

```
{
    "ID": "10",
    "location": "56",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Z LINE",
    "ORDER": "0"
}
```

Sample JSON without quotes:

```
{
    "D": 10,
    "location": 56,
    "DESCRIPTION": "Z LINE",
    "ORDER": 0
}
```

***Oracle Table description :***

```
Name         Null?    Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
ID NOT NULL NUMBER(10)   
LOCATION NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
DESCRIPTION  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50) 
ORDER   NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
```

I tried with bellow java program, but  both give same data without quotes:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(inputJsonData);
Iterator<String> keys = jsonObject.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()) {
    String key=keys.next();
    System.out.println(" Key :" +key+"  Value :"+jsonObject.get(key));
}
```

I found the solution for my own issue. Below is the program to solve this issue :

```
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        public class JsonParserDataCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputJsonData_quote="{\"magic\": \"atMSG\", \"type\": \"DT\", \"headers\": null, \"messageSchemaId\": null, \"messageSchema\": null, \"message\": {\"data\":{\"ZONE_TYPE_ID\": \"10\", \"DESCRIPTION\": \"Z LINE\", \"PICK_ORDER\": 0,\"pharmacy_location\": \"56\"} , \"beforeData\": null, \"headers\": {\"operation\": \"REFRESH\", \"changeSequence\": \"\", \"timestamp\": \"\", \"streamPosition\": \"\", \"transactionId\": \"\"}}}";
    String inputJsonData_no_quotes="{\"magic\": \"atMSG\", \"type\": \"DT\", \"headers\": null, \"messageSchemaId\": null, \"messageSchema\": null, \"message\": {\"data\":{\"ZONE_TYPE_ID\": 10, \"DESCRIPTION\": \"Z LINE\", \"PICK_ORDER\": 0,\"pharmacy_location\": \"56\"} , \"beforeData\": null, \"headers\": {\"operation\": \"REFRESH\", \"changeSequence\": \"\", \"timestamp\": \"\", \"streamPosition\": \"\", \"transactionId\": \"\"}}}";
    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(inputJsonData_quote);
    JSONObject data= (JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("message")).get("data");


    Object aObj = data.get("ZONE_TYPE_ID");
    if(aObj instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println("ZONE_TYPE_ID is Interger data type  " );
    } else  if(aObj instanceof String){
        System.out.println("ZONE_TYPE_ID is String data type  " );
    }


    jsonObject=new JSONObject(inputJsonData_no_quotes);
    data= (JSONObject) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("message")).get("data");

    aObj = data.get("ZONE_TYPE_ID");
    if(aObj instanceof Integer){
        System.out.println("ZONE_TYPE_ID is Interger data type  " );
    } else  if(aObj instanceof String){
        System.out.println("ZONE_TYPE_ID is String data type  " );
    }
}
```

}

```
    Output :
    ZONE_TYPE_ID is String data type  
    ZONE_TYPE_ID is Interger data type
```

Comment: Provide us the table definition, please.

Comment: Which JSONObect you are using. there are many APIs that provide JsonObject. What is your inputJsonData type? And almost all API, provide get<Type>() API e.g getBoolean, getInteger etc. And to get numeric value, you can call specific API and it will return null if the value is not of specific type

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I use org.json.JSONObject for parsing, But getInteger returning 10 ( Integer)  for both 10 and "10" value. I need some method to differentiate both  10 and "10" ( 10 with quotes ).